# boost multi_index - how to make it ordered-by-insert?

Tags: c++, boost

Its definition is below:

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<
  X, // the data type stored
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by< 
    boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
      boost::multi_index::composite_key<
        X,
        boost::multi_index::member<X,std::string,&X::name>,
        boost::multi_index::member<X,std::string,&X::p1>,
        boost::multi_index::member<X,std::string,&X::p2>
      >
    >
  >
> container;
```

I inserting new items with insert().

But container sorts them with the string keys, not stores inserting order.

I need it be stored.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an index to the definition for each ordering you want to be able to search by.

`boost::multi_index::sequenced` gives `std::list` like access

`boost::multi_index::random_access` gives `std::vector` like access

Note also that the `container` you define *does not* keep things in any particular order, it has `std::unordered_set` like access for it's only index.

```
boost::multi_index_container<
  X, // the data type stored
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by< 
    boost::multi_index::random_access,
    boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
      boost::multi_index::composite_key<
        X,
        boost::multi_index::member<X,std::string,&X::name>,
        boost::multi_index::member<X,std::string,&X::p1>,
        boost::multi_index::member<X,std::string,&X::p2>
      >
    >
  >
> container;

container.index<0>().erase(container.index<0>().begin() + 10) // insertion order
container.index<1>().find(some_value) // unordered
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I can't use find() for this container, meanwhile I want be able to use it, or (even better) just delete item with specified index, without loop.

Comment: @Simus You need to operate on the relevant `index`. That's why it is named  `multi_index_container`